# How to change the data dir of dockerized apache airflow?

Tags: docker, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have installed Apache Airflow using docker container on my Linux machine. The dag directory is by default is `~/airflow/dags`. How can I move it to another location, e.g. `~/src/dags`? I read some online posts that I need to modify `airflow.cfg`, however in the dockerized installation I can not find it in the ~/airflow dir.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant config variable is `dags_folder` and it *should* be present in `/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg`.

```bash
$ docker run -d --rm -p8080:8080 apache/airflow:2.7.2-python3.10 standalone
$ docker exec <container> grep -i dags_folder /opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
# Variable: AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER
dags_folder = /opt/airflow/dags
```

This means that DAGs are stored in `/opt/airflow/dags` folder *inside* the container. If you're running in Docker, you probably don't care that much about the exact location, you access it anyway via a mount:

```bash
docker run -d --rm -p8080:8080 \
           -v $HOME/dags:/opt/airflow/dags \
           apache/airflow:2.7.2-python3.10 standalone
```

(`$HOME/dags` is host folder)

If you really want it you can change the location. Rather that modifying `airflow.cfg` pass an [environment variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html):

```bash
docker run -d --rm -p8080:8080 \
           --env AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER=/src/dags \
           -v $HOME/dags:/src/dags \
           apache/airflow:2.7.2-python3.10 standalone
```